# In React js how to take input like this <MyComponent> some text input </MyComponent> ? Note I don't want to take it as props

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to take input like this :
 'my text'

so that when I call  I will be able to use 'my text' inside it.
Note: I don't want to take it as props.

Comment: I think it is impossible to do that without props. You can pass any component inside your custom component, e.g. `<MyComponent>some text</MyComponent>`, but to access the text inside the `MyComponent` you will need to use `children` prop. Learn more: [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: It is not impossible. check the answer on @sanu

Comment: Well, I wrote the same thing in my answer below. But, for your information, both solutions are still using **props**, since `{children}` is a **prop**. It is impossible to solve your question without using the **props**. What you probably meant, is that you do not want to use **attributes**, e.g. `<MyComponent text="Some text" />`.

Answer (score 1):

**i think you could create component like**

```
import React from 'react';

const Mytext = ({ children }) => {
  return <input placeholder={children} />;
};

export default Mytext;
```

**and use like**

```
<Mytext>email</Mytext>
```

Comment: It worked. So basically the keyword here is 'children' .
Thanks @Shanu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass your text the following way: `<MyComponent>Some text</MyComponent>`, then you can access "Some text" in `MyComponent` only by using `children` props. Learn more: [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

If you do not want to use props at all, then you should not pass anything directly to the components (`<MyComponent />`). In this case, you will need some global storage, like [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).